# Is it possible to make the LiDAR Scanner on an the iPhone more accurate?

Tags: lidar

I want to develope an App that scans windows and doors and tells me the accurate mesurment of all the parts (Frame, glas and so on). I know that the LiDar on the iPhone is good but it's not accurate enogh for me. I would love if someone knows a program or a way to inhance the service.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What degree of accuracy are you looking for?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.